# sending transaction from contract to contract in web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have created an ERC223 token contract. now I am testing my contract using web3.
I can transfer tokens from an externally owned account to a contract receiver. also I can check the balance of the receiver using its address.
but when I'm trying to transfer tokens from that receiver contract to another address I get such error:

```
 Error: Returned error: sender account not recognized
```

I cannot understan the cause as the receiver contract can call the token contract but cannot send transaction to it.

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: It might be you are incorrectly using the token address as sender instead of the token owner address.